# Single Mongodb database with separate data sets

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to Mongodb, and I was wandering what the best practice is for the following scenario:

I have a server with a Mongodb database. This single server should serve multiple clients, each with separate data. The separation of data is important since my collections will have a unique index on a field, which is only unique in the scope of a specific client.

What would be the best way to achieve this? Should I have a separate database for each client, or a separate group of documents?

Answer (score 0):

What I think I will end up doing is have only one dataset - one database and one collection. In order to keep the separation of data, the indexes will be on two fields: The actual unique field, and a field identifying the client